# Dry-aging at home

Tags: steak, dry-aging

I am dry aging a T-Bone steak in my refrigerator. I have placed wooden BBQ skewer sticks on top of a plastic bowl. My steak is sitting on top of the skewers and covered in a paper towel with a small air inlet opening at one end of the towel.

Most instructions about dry aging at home tell you to remove the paper towel in 24 hrs. But why? I would think I should replace it, rather than remove it, so the moisture can still escape from the meat.

Comment: You might want to reconsider this; [controlled tests](http://www.seriouseats.com/2013/01/the-food-lab-dry-age-beef-at-home.html) demonstrate fairly conclusively that it makes no perceptible difference to the texture or flavour, and there are significant potential food safety issues.

Answer (score 2):

All the dry aging instructions I've encountered (Test Kitchen, Good Eats) have the cook replace the paper towel after the first 24 hours.

I typically dry age my steaks for 4-6 days in the fridge and replace the paper towel after the first 24 hours.  The first paper towel is soaked with liquid.  The 2nd towels usually have a fraction of the moisture of the first towel.  Perhaps the authors of the instructions you've read noticed the lack of moisture in the second towel and decided it was not worth it.